# I have random tables in my SQL Database [Oracle SQL Developer]

Tags: oracle

I tried to a sql file and then import it into one of my connections in oracle sql developer. I then run the script of the downloaded sql file, but I now saw that I have hundreds of random tables in my connection I never added.

[image: How my current database looks like]

I don't know where they came from, could someone enlighten me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share the sql file with us?  How many tables already existed? Where did you get the sql file you imported?

Comment: Which Oracle user are you using? The `LOGMNR_` tables usually belong to a system account which you should **NOT** use for your regular work.

Comment: By "random" I'm guessing you mean "unexpected" :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing random, just bunch of system tables:

```
LOGMNR -> LogMiner
AQ$    -> Advanded Queuing
```